# Downscaling texture - glBlitFramebuffer vs separate render pass

Tags: opengl

I need to render some material texture of the object to the downscaled texture. When I use framebuffer with MRT I first render to the texture of the same size as a scene texture. Theoretically I can use MRT with different sizes but GL spec says:

> If the attachment sizes are not all identical, rendering will be
> limited to the largest area that can fit in all of the attachments

Then I use `glBlitFramebuffer` to downscale the render target. `glBlitFramebuffer` filter is set to GL_LINEAR. Alternatively I can use a slower method - additional render pass which renders some scene objects directly to the downscaled texture. In both cases for that material texture I use the sampler with the following parameters:

```
GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER: GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR
GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER: GL_LINEAR
```

At first glance both methods produce the same downscale texture but after careful observation there are some minor difference. Moreover downscaled texture produced by `glBlitFramebuffer` seems to have less details.

Here is my explanation:

When the material texture is rendered to the texture of the same size as scene texture mipmaps are available but later glBlitFramebuffer doesn't use them so rendering results are slightly different. Is it a correct explanation ?

Comment: I'd really not use the term "downscaled texture" for  the case where you render some things at that native resolution.

Comment: That is one reason why rendering results would be slightly different.

Comment: This question should have at least three images included: the non-downscaled image, the `glBlitFramebuffer` result, and downscaled texture-mapped result.